# Post Fedora Server upgrade to FC38, Apache httpd server no longer honors Lets Encrypt keys

Tags: httpd, lets-encrypt, fedora-server, fedora-38

The environment has twins of virtually everything, including two web server / firewall / gateway systems, and they were getting long-in-the-tooth version wise, so I decided to upgrade from `Fedora Server 30 to 38` on one of them.

My timing was curious because at the very same time I began the upgrade, without even touching (physically or electronically) the other server, it decided to fail! So, now I have a "server down" scenario. -ugh-

The update DID NOT involve crossing Apache's HTTPD's change in handling SSL keys, I don't think, because both before and after versions are sub-versions of 2.4 - `the older was 2.4.41 and the younger 2.4.57`, which is the present youngest version, which coincides with Fedora Core 38. (This is Fedora Server 38, of course.)

However, when starting, Apache's HTTPD (hereafter just called httpd), complains about the lines pertaining to the encryption keys provided by LetsEncrypt.

The keys are all current, of course, as LetsEncrypt doesn't let you get keys that last more than 3 months, I think.

The errors are like this example:

```
May 20 17:09:24 host2 httpd[3180]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 76 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/virtualhosts.conf:
May 20 17:09:24 host2 httpd[3180]: Invalid command 'SSLCertificateFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

However, a VERY basic check of the documentation yields [this link,](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html) which provides a template example which is virtually identical to what's in the `virtualhosts.conf` file - namely:

LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/www.example.com.cert"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/www.example.com.key"

Rather than me come up with a version of my own config that likewise removes the exact domains the server hosts.

I did a thorough listing of the packages that WERE installed and then that are NOW installed and don't see anything but `mod_http2-1.15.3-2.fc30.x86_64` on the old system and `mod_http2-2.0.11-2.fc38.x86_64` on the new one, and **there are some 106 modules installed** so...

Given all this focus on security and encryption, what gives?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the silly people who now run the show, all the while screaming about security, don't deign to include the module; not only is it NOT in the `httpd` software package, it's not in the `mod_http2-2.0.11-2.fc38x86_64` package EITHER!

Instead, you have to:

```
dnf install mod_ssl
```

in order to get this - and then INSTANTLY it all works.

Ya know, I think this is a BUG - I see it as a packaging bug but it's surely a documentation bug at the very least, as I actually looked. And no, buried deep in the documentation is not OK! Hence my wasted time - hope this saves someone some time.